# Athena Query results are different when using the exactly same query twice

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I use Athena for analyzing access log.
The query in question is below.

```
  select  
  count(*) as count, 
  request_url
from logs
  where target_date = '2020/11/15'
group by request_url;
```

The 'target_date' column is from partition projection.
This query returns different result when running it multiple times.
Is there something wrong?

Comment: That would suggest that the data is changing in the table.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think it is not correct, because the specified date 2020/11/15 is the data in the past so that it should not be changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that I can imagine is that you are thinking results are different because the results are in a *different* order.  Without an `order by` clause, there is no guarantee on the ordering in the result set -- and that can change from one run to the next.

So, I would suggest something like:

```
select count(*) as count, request_url
from logs
where target_date = '2020/11/15'
group by request_url
order by request_url;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I understand that when I specify 'order by count DESC' then it is fixed even when running query multiple times, however when I run query and  order the count THROUGH AWS CONSOLE, it is not fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @斯波隼斗 . . . That may be because the console brings back only a subset of the rows.